# Is there an ideal project structure for a Unreal Engine 4 C++ Project?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

This is a very broad question, but I have been developing in Unreal Engine for a while now and have always maintained the default project structure of having a main Public directory for the header files and having a main Private directory for the cpp files. It would look like this:

###### Figure 1

```
GameCore
    ├───Private
    │   ├───Abilities
    │   ├───Components
    │   ├───Core
    │   ├───Debug
    │   ├───Game
    │   ├───Interactives
    │   │   └───Ammo
    │   ├───Player
    │   └───UI
    └───Public
        ├───Abilities
        ├───Components
        ├───Core
        ├───Game
        ├───Interactives
        │   └───Ammo
        ├───Player
        └───UI
```

With that being said, I was looking through the source code of Unreal Engine and Blender and they both seem to organize their projects differently. For example:

###### Figure 2

```
GameCore
    ├───Core
    │   ├───Private
    │   └───Public
    ├───Debug
    │   ├───Private
    │   └───Public
    ├───Game
    │   ├───Private
    │   └───Public
    └───Player
        ├───Private
        └───Public
```

Are there pitfalls of choosing one structure over the other? I'm looking for concrete issues such as scalability and maintainability.

For example: I'm finding that with *Figure 1* the #include statements are shorter i.e.

```
#include "Player/CCharacterController.h"
```

Whereas *Figure 2* the #includes look like

```
#include "Core/Player/Public/CCharacterController.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those instances where "form vs function" comes into play.

Unreal includes a C# build system to simplify and unify the build process.

The theory behind the longer paths is: at compile time all of the relevant files are included through the C# build file.

There is nothing wrong with your approach, even if it differs with certain projects. It is simply a design decision.